# Repeat() function in R to retry url when 503

Tags: r, web-crawler, repeat, http-status-code-503

I was crawling a quite unstable website, which sometimes collapse into 503 and could only be fixed when refreshed. So I created these code to ask my crawler to retry the 503 page until the content has been passed to a variable:

```
repeat{
  info = NA
  info = read_html(url2)
  if(is.na(info) == F) {
    break
    }
}
info
```

But for some reason this does not work. The system still throw me this, which it should not:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.
> info
[1] NA
```

Sometimes it even gives me this, but under such condition the content could be passed to the variable info with no problem:

```
Warning messages:
1: In for (i in seq_along(cenv$extra)) { :
  closing unused connection 6 (url)
2: In for (i in seq_along(cenv$extra)) { :
  closing unused connection 5 (url)
```

How can I build a code to retry the 503 pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the error, this should work:

```
counter = 0

repeat {
  counter = counter + 1
  info = tryCatch(
    read_html(url2),
    # if you want to capture warnings as well
    warning = function(w) {
      Sys.sleep(30)
      NA
    },
    error = function(e) {
      Sys.sleep(30)  
      NA
    }
  )
  if(!is.na(info) | counter >= 10) {
    break
  }
}
```

This is also the gist of what `purrr::insistently` does.

Comment: How can I add a system sleep time if an error occurs then? I don't wanna press it too hard on the poor webpage...

Comment: You can add calls to `Sys.sleep`, see updated answer which will wait 30 seconds in between each try

Comment: Can I sent a limit for the number of trials so that after this many times of trial you just break the loop?